# Flutter: How to extract mode of payment in razorpay_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using razorpay_flutter for payments in Flutter, and I want to retrieve the mode of payment like Debit card/ NetBanking/ UPI, is there any way to retrieve the mode of payment, after payment successful?

Comment: The Razorpay flutter plugin doesn't return detailed order details with the success response. What you can do is fetch the order payments details with the order id you receive with the success response via this GET API endpoint: ``https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders/:order_id/payments``. More information can be found here https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#fetch-an-order-with-id

Comment: @OMiShah thank you, so is this API free or is it paid, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Obviously, it's free for Razorpay merchants.

Comment: @OMiShah, Im getting the order_id itself as null in payment success response, without order_id itself, I cannot use that API which you suggested. Can you help?

Comment: Do check the official razorpay flutter integration doc available on their official website. You should read and implement as described

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot